# What does the F in front of brush names mean?

Tags: interface, terminology

What does the `F` in front of brush names in the selector stand for?

[image: Brush screenshot]

---

This question may seem a little trivial, but it always made me wonder..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It stands for [Fake User](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/what-does-users-means-in-term-of-datablocks). Since the default brushes all have fake users, the *"F"* shows up in front of the name.

***Note:*** This applies to many other data-blocks, not just brushes, its just noticeable since fake-user is enabled by default, but it can be used used for meshes, curves, actions, fonts... too.

Comment: Yes: the "fake user" means the brush will be saved with the file even if nothing is using it.