# Cyan Color Origin Point, but Only One Scene

Tags: interface

I have already read [Cyan origin dot mystery](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19178/cyan-origin-dot-mystery), so please don't close this question as a duplicate of it.

[image]

In the above linked question, Ray Mairlot [explains](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19179/20508) that a cyan origin point can be caused by an object being in multiple scenes. He includes a screenshot of the *Properties panel > Object tab*, which shows that there are two copies of the object across the scenes. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I have a cyan origin point, but only one scene. I do have multiple copies of the object, though, like shown in the second screenshot. **Where is my other copy of the object and how did it occur?**

Here is my .blend:

[image]

Comment: I downloaded your file, every dot is orange!

Comment: @joshsanfelici The dot in the screenshot belongs to an _Empty > Plain Axes_ inside the piano used for _Object Texture Coordinates_. Did you check it?

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice. Yes it's cyan and I don't know why (I think it shouldn't: I deleted all the objects one by one, it remained the empty with two items, then I deleted it and nothing remained).

Comment: I think you have managed somehow to corrupt some objects.You can select all the objects in the scene and then delete them.2 of them dont get deleted (you can these 2 in the outliner)(Also that might be caused by moving blender files that you appended in your current project)Maybe the blue dot is related to this somehow.

Comment: Maybe the empty shares data with the 2 corrupted objects?(Plus thats why its cyan?)