# Store material without an object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

When I search for how I can keep a material when removing an object, I only get answers to the opposite question: How to remove the material. I want to remove the object but want to keep the material. Is that possible?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/what-does-users-means-in-term-of-datablocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The material isn't deleted with the object; the former will only have 0 users and hence will be deleted on reopening the file. To avoid that use [*Fake User* option](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/options.html#material-naming-and-linking):

> Gives the material a ‘fake user’, to keep the material data-block saved in the blend-file, even if it has no real users.

[image: image example of fake user]

More info on datablocks and fake user - [What does "users" means in term of datablocks ?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/what-does-users-means-in-term-of-datablocks)