# Cannot use the sculptdraw tool

Tags: modeling

I was sculpting a model with the sculptdraw tool and I accidentally pressed the "2" under the icon (circled in green in image). I figured this out by pressing it several more times so I have 4 scupltdraw tools (Circled in red in picture). Now when I try and use the tool nothing happens. All other tools are working fine. I am guessing all I need to do is delete the duplicates but I don't know how to do that and which tool is the original.

Thanks in advance
[image: Blender picture showing the issue]

Comment: If my answer doesn't solve your problem somehow, can you upload your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and share it with us so we can see if there is another issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you can't use the tool since duplicating brushes shouldn't affect their properties however, you basically made duplicates of the main brush and then made them permanent by ticking the F. To fix, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the **X** which will unlink the brush and set the number of users to 0. Select the red paintbrush icon and select the other duplicate(s) and repeat, also untick the **F** as well.

This is how your brush menu should look after. Notice the 0 beside the duplicate brushes and the F beside your original.

[image]

Now that you have unlinked the dupes, save your file and open it again (can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and select it at the top). Select the icon again and select your original brush(set).

Since datablocks are so key in Blender, I'd recommend reading on how to identify and know what is happening in the future as this applies to other areas such as materials, nodes etc. [What does "users" means in term of datablocks?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/what-does-users-means-in-term-of-datablocks?noredirect=1&lq=1)