# how to delete duplicated brushes in sculpting mode

Tags: sculpting

[image]

if i save the object as blender file it will contain the brushes i added by mistake so how to remove it from the list , btw how to keep one duplicated brushes to default-reload (close blender and reopen a new project),and are there anyway to load different brushes download from web as default? much more thx!!!!

Answer (score 7):

Click on the Brush you wish to delete. In the tool panel and <kbd>Shift</kbd> click the X to delete. You will see a zero appears before the brush name in the pop-out tool-shelf. If you save and re-open or *Revert* - the brush will be gone...

[image]

You can find a link to an Add-on with more brushes on [Blendernation](http://www.blendernation.com/2015/02/17/free-blender-brushes/)
Brushes are essentially just textures that use the alpha cancel. You can use textures from other programs like these at [Pixologic](https://pixologic.com/zbrush/downloadcenter/alpha/) or just create your own in your favorite drawing program...

Ben Simmonds has also got a few .Blend files with brushes that are worth exploring - like this one on [Blendswap](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/67891). And to answer your last question I can quote him " ...you can append these brushes into your default blendfile to have them permanently avaliable. Just load the default blend file, then hit File>Append, select the brush blend file, select brushes, and shift-select the two Trim brushes inside. Click Link/Append from Library, and the brushes will now be avaliable. Then just save your startup file (Ctrl-U) to update the default .blend file."

Comment: why there's .blender111 shows up what is this file?

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/65341/12

Comment: Is there a particular reason this is so convoluted? Why can't I just delete a brush I don't want without quiting/reloading? Why is it called "fake user"?