# texture paint : how to switch between texture stencil and solid color paint

Tags: texture-painting

When i do texture paint, i can draw with solid color , then when i want to draw using texture (stencil mode) i will add texture to the brush. Now if i want to go back to draw using solid color how can i do this? i ussually have to delete texture from the brush. And if i want to use texture stencil again  , i can't do it in tool property, i have to go to texture tab to select previous texture brush. This is silly to go back and forth these tabs. There must be a faster way . Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make as many brush presets as you want.

[image]

Comment: Inside red-framed boxes, what does F stand for and what do you use it for?

Comment: It's called Fake User. It appears frequently in Blender. If you create something (mesh data, material, animation, brush, etc.) then none of the object use it in the project, Blender won't save it in the blend file. If you apply a fake user, then Blender will save it (just like if something use it). https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/what-does-users-means-in-term-of-datablocks