# Error meanign: ID user decrement error: OBmesh34_mesh34-geometry.088 (from '[Main]'): 0 <= 0

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I am running a multi-view rendering script in blender-python version 2.78. Rendering itself is happening successfully, but I get the following error messages

ID user decrement error: OBmesh34_mesh34-geometry.088 (from '[Main]'): 0 <= 0

I would like to know what is the meaning of this error and why would it generally occur.

Thank you!

Comment: Objects in blender have users. A mesh object is a user of its mesh. At least an object can have zero users aka an orphan. The error is warning that somehow the system is trying to remove a user from an already orphan object.  Why it is occurring for your script may be more apparent on seeing your script.

Comment: Thanks! I am quite not able to understand that blender have users and mesh object is a user of its mesh. Can you give an example of what an user does and why do we need to have many users for one object(for ex. a mesh being an object)?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/what-does-users-means-in-term-of-datablocks